# FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: android, gps, stack-overflow

I just try to do application that gives the current position map(longitude and latitude values)
I just created a **GPstracker.java** and use operation there
I only need to get only the two values related to the button press
its helpfull for my future coding I am a beginner guys 
here is my **Main Activity** Code

```
 package com.example.shellz.gps_locator;

   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
   import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
   import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
   import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.view.Menu;
   import android.view.MenuItem;
   import android.widget.Button;
   import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button btn;
GPStracker gps;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.location_btn);


    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            gps=new GPStracker(MainActivity.this);
            if(gps.canGetLocation())
            {
                Double latitude=gps.getLatitude();
                Double longitude=gps.getLongitude();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),latitude+" and "+longitude+" ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else
            {
                gps.showSettingsAlert();
            }
        }
    });


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

here is my **GPStracker.java** here I do the all operation related to my project

```
   package com.example.shellz.gps_locator;

   import android.Manifest;
   import android.app.AlertDialog;
   import android.app.Service;
   import android.content.Context;
   import android.content.DialogInterface;
   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
   import android.location.Location;
   import android.location.LocationListener;
   import android.location.LocationManager;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.os.IBinder;
   import android.provider.Settings;
   import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
   import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
   import  android.widget.Toast;


public class GPStracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

private static final Location TODO = null;
private final Context mContext;

//gps status
Boolean isGPSEnable = false;

//network status
Boolean isNetwokEnable = false;

Boolean CangetLoaction = false;

Location location;
Double latitude;
Double longitude;

private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_FOR_UPDATE = 10;

private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1;

protected LocationManager locationmanger;

public GPStracker(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
    getLocation();
}

public Location getLocation() {
    try {

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return TODO;
        }

        locationmanger = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        isGPSEnable = locationmanger.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        isNetwokEnable = locationmanger.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (!isNetwokEnable && !isGPSEnable) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Network Avialiable", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            this.CangetLoaction = true;
            if (isNetwokEnable) {

                locationmanger.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES, MIN_DISTANCE_FOR_UPDATE, this);
                if (locationmanger != null) {


                    location = locationmanger.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if (location != null) {
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();

                    }
                }
            }
            if (isGPSEnable) {
                locationmanger.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES, MIN_DISTANCE_FOR_UPDATE, this);
                if (locationmanger != null) {


                    location = locationmanger.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if (location != null) {
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();

                    }
                }
            }

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return location;
}

public void stopUsingGPS() {
    if (locationmanger != null) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        locationmanger.removeUpdates(GPStracker.this);
    }
}

public double getLatitude(){
    if(location != null){
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
    }

    // return latitude
    return latitude;
}

public double getLongitude(){
    if(location != null){
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }

    // return longitude
    return longitude;
}

public boolean canGetLocation() {
    return this.canGetLocation();
}

public void showSettingsAlert(){
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

    // On pressing Settings button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    // on pressing cancel button
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
}


@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
```

}

here the errors what i get while running

```
06-25 17:14:36.296 10750-10750/com.example.shellz.gps_locator E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at com.example.shellz.gps_locator.GPStracker.canGetLocation(GPStracker.java:147)
at com.example.shellz.gps_locator.GPStracker.canGetLocation(GPStracker.java:147)
at com.example.shellz.gps_locator.GPStracker.canGetLocation(GPStracker.java:147)
at com.example.shellz.gps_locator.GPStracker.canGetLocation(GPStracker.java:147)
at com.example.shellz.gps_locator.GPStracker.canGetLocation(GPStracker.java:147)
at com.example.shellz.gps_locator.GPStracker.canGetLocation(GPStracker.java:147)
at com.example.shellz.gps_locator.GPStracker.canGetLocation(GPStracker.java:147)
at com.example.shellz.gps_locator.GPStracker.canGetLocation(GPStracker.java:147)
at com.example.shellz.gps_locator.GPStracker.canGetLocation(GPStracker.java:147)
at com.example.shellz.gps_locator.GPStracker.canGetLocation(GPStracker.java:147)
at com.example.shellz.gps_locator.GPStracker.canGetLocation(GPStracker.java:147)
at com.example.shellz.gps_locator.GPStracker.canGetLocation(GPStracker.java:147)
at com.example.shellz.gps_locator.GPStracker.canGetLocation(GPStracker.java:147)
at com.example.shellz.gps_locator.GPStracker.canGetLocation(GPStracker.java:147)
at com.example.shellz.gps_locator.GPStracker.canGetLocation(GPStracker.java:147)
at com.example.shellz.gps_locator.GPStracker.canGetLocation(GPStracker.java:147)
at com.example.shellz.gps_locator.GPStracker.canGetLocation(GPStracker.java:147)
at com.example.shellz.gps_locator.GPStracker.canGetLocation(GPStracker.java:147)
at com.example.shellz.gps_locator.GPStracker.canGetLocation(GPStracker.java:147)
at com.example.shellz.gps_locator.GPStracker.canGetLocation(GPStracker.java:147)
at com.example.shellz.gps_locator.GPStracker.canGetLocation(GPStracker.java:147)
at com.example.shellz.gps_locator.GPStracker.canGetLocation(GPStracker.java:147)
at com.example.shellz.gps_locator.GPStracker.canGetLocation(GPStracker.java:147)
at com.example.shellz.gps_locator.GPStracker.canGetLocation(GPStracker.java:147)
at com.example.shellz.gps_locator.GPStracker.canGetLocation(GPStracker.java:147)
at com.example.shellz.gps_locator.GPStracker.canGetLocation(GPStracker.java:147)
at com.example.shellz.gps_locator.GPStracker.canGetLocation(GPStracker.java:147)
at com.example.shellz.gps_locator.GPStracker.canGetLocation(GPStracker.java:147)
at com.example.shellz.gps_locator.GPStracker.canGetLocation(GPStracker.java:147)
at com.example.shellz.gps_locator.GPStracker.canGetLocation(GPStracker.java:147)
at com.example.shellz.gps_locator.GPStracker.canGetLocation(GPStracker.java:147)
at com.example.shellz.gps_locator.GPStracker.canGetLocation(GPStracker.java:147)
at com.example.shellz.gps_locator.GPStracker.canGetLocation(GPStracker.java:147)
at com.example.shellz.gps_locator.GPStracker.canGetLocation(GPStracker.java:147)
at com.example.shellz.gps_locator.GPStracker.canGetLocation(GPStracker.java:147)
at com.example.shellz.gps_locator.GPStracker.canGetLocation(GPStracker.java:147)
at com.example.shellz.gps_locator.GPStracker.canGetLocation(GPStracker.java:147)
at com.example.shellz.gps_locator.GPStracker.canGetLocation(GPStracker.java:147)
at com.example.shellz.gps_locator.GPStracker.canGetLocation(GPStracker.java:147)
at com.example.shellz.gps_locator.GPStracker.canGetLocation(GPStracker.java:147)
at com.example.shellz.gps_locator.GPStracker.canGetLocation(GPStracker.java:147)
at com.example.shellz.gps_locator.GPStracker.canGetLocation(GPStracker.java:147)
at com.example.shellz.gps_locator.GPStracker.canGetLocation(GPStracker.java:147)
at com.example.shellz.gps_locator.GPStracker.canGetLocation(GPStracker.java:147)
at com.example.shellz.gps_locator.GPStracker.canGetLocation(GPStracker.java:147)
at com.example.shellz.gps_locator.GPStracker.canGetLocation(GPStracker.java:147)
at com.example.shellz.gps_locator.GPStracker.canGetLocation(GPStracker.java:147)
at com.example.shellz.gps_locator.GPStracker.canGetLocation(GPStracker.java:147)
at com.example.shellz.gps_locator.GPStracker.canGetLocation(GPStracker.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because of the function calling itself. Its an endless loop.

```
public boolean canGetLocation() {
    return this.canGetLocation();
}
```

> Modify this function to remove this error.

This think you want to change it to :

```
public boolean canGetLocation() {
        return this.CangetLoaction;
    }
```